# Reproduce audio files in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, audio-player

I'm using vscode and I can open PDF files, image files (JPG, PNG, ...), and a lot of different visualizations for different files but, what about audio files (wav, mp3, ogg)? Is there any extension to do this?

Comment: if Node.js can play audio files you can add a menu option to the explorer to play an audio file by writing an extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sukumo28.wav-preview

It seems that this extension supports wav, mp3, ogg.

Comment: Good one! Thank you! It's sad it's not possible to reproduce other kinds of audio files but it's a start.